Advanced indexing in xarray combined with slice?
I am trying to extract a time-series of temperatures at point locations from an xarray dataset, with different start and end times for the time-series for each location.
I have a point dataframe with lat, lon and start and end times:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'lat': [-37.4, -39.1], 'lon': [140.8, 141.2], 'time_start':['2000-04-01', '2000-03-01'], 'time_end':['2000-07-01', '2000-06-01']}
)

I have a xarray dataset of temperatures with lat, lon and time dimensions:
da = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(4, 3, 10), 
[
    ("lat", [-37, -38, -39, -40]), 
    ('lon', [140, 141, 142]),
    ('time', pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=10, freq='MS'))
])

ds = da.to_dataset(name="temp")

I can use advanced indexing to get time-series at each location for the entire time range, like so:
points_xr =df.to_xarray()
joined = ds.sel(lat=points_xr['lat'], lon=points_xr['lon'], method='nearest')
joined

>>>
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (index: 2, time: 10)
Coordinates:
    lat      (index) int32 -37 -39
    lon      (index) int32 141 141
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-02-01 ... 2000-10-01
  * index    (index) int64 0 1
Data variables:
    temp     (index, time) float64 0.3114 0.5535 0.05429 ... 0.2562 0.8687

I would then like to refine this to only have the temperatures at each index between the time_start and time_end. I have tried this:
joined = joined.sel(time=slice(points_xr['time_start'], points_xr['time_end']))
>>> ValueError: cannot use non-scalar arrays in a slice for xarray indexing: ['2000-04-01' '2000-03-01']

The best solution I can come up with is to use the pandas apply function to pull the array into a column in the original dataframe, like this:
df['array'] = df.apply(lambda row: joined.sel(index=row.name, time=slice(row['time_start'], row['time_end']))['temp'].values, 
axis=1)

However, this is very slow for my larger dataframe, and so I'd like to know if there's a way to do this in the indexing in xarray, without doing a pandas apply.
